# How to add admin functionality to allow ability to choose different field group to display on webpage using Advanced Custom Fields?

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

Currently I have a field group defined using the ACF plugin, showing: title and icon and a link, on a specif area of my page. I want to give one of my Content Contributors the ability to choose from two different field groups for that same area of my page depending on their needs. Is this possible? If so how would I go about it doing? Thank you.

```
<h2 class="icon" style="background:url(<?php the_field('top_left_icon');?>) no-repeat left center;"><?php the_field('top_left_title');?></h2>
<?php the_field('top_left_text');?>

<?php if( (get_field('top_left_button_text')) && (get_field('top_left_button_link'))){?>
<a class="button" href="<?php the_field('top_left_button_link'); ?>"><?php the_field('top_left_button_text'); ?></a>
<?php } ?>
```

And here is a screen grab of what that looks like implemented in the ACF plugin admin side of things:

[image]

Comment: What code did you use for the custom fields?

Comment: This seems extremely specific to plugin. Please elaborate on your implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve what I needed, I had to detect if any of the fields (in my case only 3 were necessary) were left empty. If any of them were empty, then the test failed and the "else" part of the code gets executed (the else part contains markup for the "alternate field group").

Here is my code:

```
<?php if( get_field('top_left_icon') && get_field('top_left_title') && get_field('top_left_text') !== '' ): ?>

<h2 class="calendar" style="background:url(<?php the_field('top_left_icon');?>) no-repeat left center;"><?php the_field('top_left_title');?></h2>
<?php the_field('top_left_text');?>

<?php if( (get_field('top_left_button_text')) && (get_field('top_left_button_link'))){?>
    <a class="button" href="<?php the_field('top_left_button_link'); ?>"><?php the_field('top_left_button_text'); ?></a>
<?php } ?>
```

In addition, I had to create an "alternate" field group in WordPress Admin area for my page. Hope this helps anybody that may have something similar.